# Mysql full text not returning results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table with a two full text indexes defined. The table layout from "show create table upload" statment is:

```
CREATE TABLE `upload` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `when_uploaded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bywho` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `bywho` (`bywho`),
  KEY `when_uploaded` (`when_uploaded`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `notes` (`notes`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The sql used to search is:

```
select * from upload where match(notes) against('comments' in boolean mode)
```

I have verified that the word "comments" appears in at least one of the 4 test rows. I can search the title using:

```
select * from upload where match(title) against('upload' in boolean mode)
```

Without issue on the same table and have it return results. I have different words that I have tried that I know are in the notes field but to no avail.

I know this search worked before. I changed the minimum word size to 3. Deleted the indexes for title and notes and re-added them. Title works, notes doesn't.

Since I'm using "in boolean mode" the 50% noise rule should not come into effect. I am running on 5.6.10 MySQL. I have tried these searches both from my PHP script and the mysql command line. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried adding quotes to the column name notes?
select * from upload where match(`notes`) against('comments' in boolean mode)

Comment: @Jester  Yes. I get a syntax error error.